# How to use Mongoose to query keyword in 2 fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Lets say I have a Mongoose model like this:

```
var AdSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    vehicleDescription: String,
    adDescription: String,
    ...
});
```

I want to search both fields for the same key word, for example

find all WHERE vehicleDescription contains the word TEST, OR adDescription contains the word TEST.

It needs to be case sensitive also.

Currently I can query one field like this:

```
var query = {};
query['adDescription'] = ({ $regex: search.keyWord, $options: 'i' });
```

But I need to search both fields at the same time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for more than one fields at the same time by specifying the field and value in a `{field 1: value 1}, {field 2: value 2},...,{field n: value n}`format in the `find()`function. Additionally, you can also specify various conditions that the results must satisfy, such as AND, OR etc.

In your case, a sample code in Node.js would look like this

```
var result = db.collection('AdSchema').find({
    $or: [ {vehicleDescription : { $regex: search.keyWord, $options: 'i' }}, { adDescription: { $regex: search.keyWord, $options: 'i' } } ]
});
```

For more detail, refer the [documentation page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) for MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator, so `adModel.find({$or:[{"vehicleDescription": /keyword/gi },{"adDescription": /keyword/gi}]})`.

I hope this helps :)